# How to restrict to load same js multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am talking about the CakePHP Helper. I want to load the JS files using the helper of CakePHP.

Consider that the construction of the Helper class will load all necessary JS files.

But, I need to call that Helper in a single view multiple times. So, it's possible that the JS files will be called multiple times. I want to load those JS files only once.

Can anyone help me to cover this?

This will be my Helper script

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

/**
 * @alias Mathjax Class for helper
 * @description This class is to define helper in cakephp.
 */
class MathjaxHelper extends AppHelper {

    /*
     * Constructor of the class.
     */
    function __construct(View $View, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($View, $settings);
        //login to load all necessary JS files.
    }

    function create() {
        //this function will return the helper html
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use HtmlHelper::script

If you use [HtmlHelper::script](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3ascript) method, with `'inline' => false`, to load the js files they will by default be included **once**.

#### Layout file

To use this method, ensure that in the layout file the `$scripts_for_layout` variable is echoed out. E.g.:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...

        <?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

#### View files

In your views, elements or helpers - simply ensure the script method is called using the inline parameter:

```
<?php $this->Html->script('my', array('inline' => false)); ?>
```

In this way it doesn't matter how often you call the script method with a given js file - it will appear in the resultant html output only once.

Comment: You can also use `$options['once']` as per documentation

Comment: True, but that's only relevant if js scripts are dumped inline in a view file (which - shouldn't be the case and isn't something I encourage).